# WebGL fragment shaders for SNES S-PPU?

Tags: glsl, webgl, emulation

I’m not very experienced with WebGL and want to ask if this project is potentially feasible and also for a few hints about what direction I may want to take.

I’d like to implement all of the logic required to render an SNES PPU in fragment shaders using WebGL. I have a mostly cycle-accurate JavaScript SNES emulator, which runs at a good speed, except PPU drawing is slow. I have other plans to speed it up, but someone made a suggestion to do it with GLSL, and it captured my attention.

This requires access to the following data structures:

A 64k 8-bit (or 32k 16-bit is also convenient) buffer to represent VRAM,
About 1k of data per scanline, of which there can be up to 240

It requires doing a lot of lookups, address calculations, reads and comparisons, and holding a bunch of variables in memory at once. S-PPU color math is non-trivial.

I’d have two general approaches in mind -
A non-pipelined approach, where each shader takes its screen position and does all the lookups and math to output a final pixel value.

Or a more complicated deferred rendering-style setup where lookups, comparisons, etc. happen in stages between multiple buffers.

Is this a feasible project with WebGL fragment shaders? Any hints as to which direction I should head?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like we have enough information in the body of this question to evaluate the feasibility or recommend solutions. Can you edit the question to get into more concrete detail? It may help to narrow the scope to one PPU operation you need help implementing - then, if the answers to that question don't scale to the next operation you want to implement, you can post a second question to ask about that. This way you can fully-specify the expected input and output for a set of use cases without the question getting overwhelming in scope.

Comment: Hmm, the S-PPU is seriously involved. Those 2 buffers I spoke of are all the input needed to render a frame, I guess I could start by narrowing what sort of data structures to use to access that data

Comment: Is there no one feature you can isolate, even if it only gives you one tenth of a functioning PPU? Breaking things into smaller steps usually yields better answers here, even if it means you need to ask a follow-up question later to keep building toward a full PPU. If you don't narrow it down, then you're limiting your pool of users who could potentially answer this question to those who 1) see your question, 2) understand WebGL, 3) already understand the entirety of the PPU deeply, 4) have time to mentally model a complete emulation of every PPU feature, for free. That's a small pool!

Comment: My understanding is that [PPU behavior is not entirely known](https://github.com/bsnes-emu/bsnes/issues/138) so in the fullest most general sense, I'm not sure this question is answerable.

Comment: @OrgnlDave To clarify - I'm not trying to discourage you from what you've generally proposed or from asking questions about it. The answer to "Is this a feasible project with WebGL fragment shaders?" is "probably," which doesn't help much. In contrast, a focused question on how to emulate a specific PPU op with a shader would likely be more helpful to you & others. Specifying exactly what you want the shader to do will help those who have shader skills but w/out detailed PPU knowledge answer your questions.